# HMAC validation for embedded Shopify apps

Tags: shopify

I am working on my first Shopify app. While it's not embedded (setting in application settings) it works okay but when I turn it into embedded mode then I get invalid HMAC error.

I searched for different kind of validation for embedded apps but didn't find anything. It seems that it should be the same for usual and embedded apps

UPDATE (with solution):
the embedded app adds one additional param:
protocol=https://

This additional param must be included in HMAC calculation (in case it is embedded app). Important thing that this param MUST BE NOT ENCODED when you pass this param for HMAC calculation.

Comment: show us the code, error trace, relevant config and logs.

Comment: I just noticed that when I changed app to embedded I started to get one additional parameter: protocol=https:// I tried to add it to HMAC calculation but I still didn't get the same HMAC as $_GET['hmac'].

I generate HMAC of:
1. $_GET['shop']
2. $_GET['timestamp']
3. As I mentioned before I tried to add $_GET['protocol']

Interesting thing that on not embedded app I calculate correct HMAC.  When I set my shopify app as embedded my HMAC calculation becomes wrong